# Apache cannot change location errorlog in virtual host

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, apache-2.4, django

I use the directive

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error1.log
```

in a virtual host.

But the output error is still in error.log. I have restarted apache but things doesn't work. However, the relocation of access log works fine.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and running a django server.

Apache version is Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Does anybody know how to solve this?

The whole site conf is below:

```
WSGIPythonPath /srv/tetra_proxy

<VirtualHost *:59020>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/tetra_proxy/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error1.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access1.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/tetra_proxy/tetra_proxy/wsgi.py

    <Directory  /srv/tetra_proxy/tetra_proxy>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you sure the site related to this configuration is enabled? 
Can you paste the full virtualhost configuration file?

Comment: @pixeline I am sure it's enabled, otherwise the access log relocation wouldn't work. Also the error1.log was created by apache too.